# How do amps affect RPMs?

Tags: motor

I bought a replacement pellet stove auger motor rated at: `120V, 0.51 amp, 1 RPM`.  (ASIN: [B0032D26I6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0032D26I6)).  I installed it into the stove and it works, but the feed rate is too fast and my flame is too high.  I think I got the wrong part.  *(This is actually a dangerous situation since the stove will overheat on high setting and shut down)*

I've been researching the correct part and I found what I think to be the correct motor with a rating of: `120V 60Hz 0.72FLA 1RPM`.  (Part #: [EF-001](http://www.enviro.com/partsSearch/show_images.php?PartNum=EF-001).  ASIN: [B0095LLIII](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0095LLIII) - You can see the specs on the picture of the product).

I talked to someone who indicated to me that the amp rating would affect the rotation.  Is that true?  How does that work?  Would this second motor "slow down" my pellet feed rate?  If it is not the amps, then what would affect the feed rate?

### EDIT:

I bought the second auger motor, EF-001, and installed it this morning.  Now the flame is the correct height (because of the correct pellet feed rate).  **Why would 2 motors, both 1RPM feed at different rates?**

*Standard US 120V electrical service*

Comment: We need to know more about these motors. Actual part numbers would be ideal.

Comment: Sure thing @MattYoung.  I added the urls to the part numbers in the question.  Also added part numbers where I have them.

Answer (score 2):

> **what would affect the feed rate?**

- the RPM of the motor
- the pitch and diameter of the auger helix

The control system should adjust the RPM (or cycle the motor on and off) to provide the overall feed-rate you need. Apparently some systems have a thermostat that controls the feed-rate (e.g. see p31 of [random manual](http://www.enviro.com/images/manuals-brochures/owners-manuals/C-11219%20Instruction%20EF2%20Domestic%20Owner%27s%20Manual.pdf)).

Comment: I'm pretty sure the control system cycle's the motor on and off.  I think it is 2-3 seconds on and 5-8 seconds off.

Comment: What is the helix?

Comment: @Jess: The controls should allow you to change those on-off periods indirectly. The helix is the shape formed by each of the outer edges of the augur that pushes pellets into the burner. You can't change that.

Comment: See updated question

Answer (score 1):

The second motor is also rated to be 1 RPM (fixed), so it won't be any slower.

It's a more powerful motor (0.51A stall vs. 0.72A stall), so it may actually run a bit faster under load.

You probably want a motor that is rated for fewer RPM and is of similar physical size.

Comment: Almost all pellet stove motors are 1 RPM.  You can find ones with more like 2 or 4 RPM, but 1 RPM is very standard.

Comment: @Jess What's the solution? Change the screw pitch?

Comment: Haha.  I don't know the solution at all.  There is nothing configurable at all that I know of on the motor.  You just install it with one hex screw and 2 wires.